# Use only one SQL query to get result in pages

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I want to split XML response into pages because I have too many XML items to send back. I tried this:

***XML request:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reconcile>
  <start_date>2018-04-08T11:02:44</start_date>
  <end_date>2019-10-08T11:02:44</end_date>
  <page>1</page>
</reconcile>
```

***JAXB:***

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "reconcile")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Reconcile {

    @XmlElement(name = "start_date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
    private LocalDateTime start_date;
    @XmlElement(name = "end_date")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class)
    private LocalDateTime end_date;
    @XmlElement(name = "page")
    private String page;
    ...../// getters and setters
}
```

***SQL query:***

```
public List<PaymentTransactions> transactionsByDate(LocalDateTime start_date, LocalDateTime end_date, Merchants merchant, Terminals terminal) throws Exception {

        String hql = "select e from " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e where e.created_at >= ? and e.created_at <= ?";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter(0, start_date).setParameter(1, end_date);
        List<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactions = (List<PaymentTransactions>) query.getResultList();
        return paymentTransactions;
}
```

Return XML:

```
 List<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactions = transactionsService
                    .transactionsByDate(reconcile.getStart_date(), reconcile.getEnd_date(), merchant, terminal);

            ReconcilePaymentResponses pr = new ReconcilePaymentResponses();
            pr.setPage("1");
            pr.setPages_count("10");
            pr.setPer_page("4");
            pr.setTotal_count(String.valueOf(paymentTransactions.size()));

            for (int e = 0; e < paymentTransactions.size(); e++) {
                PaymentTransactions pt = paymentTransactions.get(e);

                ReconcilePaymentResponse obj = new ReconcilePaymentResponse();
                obj.setTransaction_type(pt.getType());
                pr.getPaymentResponse().add(obj);
            }

            return pr;
```

XML Response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<payment_responses page="1" per_page="4" total_count="5" pages_count="10">
    <payment_response>
        <transaction_type>Type</transaction_type>
    </payment_response>
    <payment_response>
        <transaction_type>Type</transaction_type>
    </payment_response>
    <payment_response>
        <transaction_type>Type</transaction_type>
    </payment_response>
    .........
</payment_responses>
```

I would like somehow to split `<payment_response>....</payment_response>` into pages in order to reduce memory overhead. For example when I send 1 I would like to return the first 10.

The current proposal uses 2 SQL queries. I would like to use only one SQL query:

I created a new PageInfo class to store the paging info.  Added a query to get the total number of rows and set my page_info.  Then limited the number of results from your query.  Finally set the values to ReconcilePaymentResponse.

```
Class PageInfo {
    int current_page;
    int page_count;
    int per_page;
    int total_page;

    //constructor
    public PageInfo(int current_page, int page_count, int per_page) {
        //assign them
    }
    //getters
    //setters
}
```

SQL Query:

```
public List<PaymentTransactions> transactionsByDate(LocalDateTime start_date, LocalDateTime end_date, Merchants merchant, Terminals terminal,
    PageInfo pageInfo) throws Exception {

    //figure out number of total rows
    String count_hql = "select count(*) from " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e where e.created_at >= ? and e.created_at <= ?";
    Query count_query = entityManager.createQuery(count_hql);
    int count = countQuery.uniqueResult();

    //figure out total pages
    int total_page = (int)Math.ceil(count/(double)pageInfo.getPerPage());
    pageInfo.setTotal_Page(total_page);

    String hql = "select e from " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e where e.created_at >= ? and e.created_at <= ?";
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql)
        //set starting point
        .setFirstResult((pageInfo.getCurrentPage()-1) * pageInfo.getPerPage)
        //set max rows to return
        .setMaxResults(pageInfo.getPerPage)
        .setParameter(0, start_date).setParameter(1, end_date);
    List<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactions = (List<PaymentTransactions>) query.getResultList();
    return paymentTransactions;
}
```

Return XML:

```
        //initialize PageInfo with desired values
        PageInfo page_info = new PageInfo(1,10,4);
        List<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactions = transactionsService
            .transactionsByDate(reconcile.getStart_date(), reconcile.getEnd_date(), merchant, terminal, page_info);  // pass in page_info

        ReconcilePaymentResponses pr = new ReconcilePaymentResponses();
        pr.setPage(page_info.getCurrentPage());
        pr.setPages_count(page_info.getPageCount());
        pr.setPer_page(page_info.getPerPage());
        pr.setTotal_count(String.valueOf(paymentTransactions.size()));

        for (int e = 0; e < paymentTransactions.size(); e++) {
            PaymentTransactions pt = paymentTransactions.get(e);

            ReconcilePaymentResponse obj = new ReconcilePaymentResponse();
            obj.setTransaction_type(pt.getType());
            pr.getPaymentResponse().add(obj);
        }

        return pr;
```

How I can use only one SQL query?

Comment: I think, you can use offset mysql pagination: https://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm

Comment: also `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10; ` - Retrieve rows 6-15

Comment: But you may need to sort items first so that your pagination will return records in consistent order

Comment: Can you please paste complete working example so I can rate it?

Comment: 2 query seem not a big deal in your case.

Comment: Is it MySQL or another db engine?

Comment: @Limonka MariaDB - latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fast option:**

You can use **COUNT(*) OVER()** as the last column in your resultset, it will store the total number of rows that would be returned if there was no limit:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, COUNT(*) OVER() as Total
FROM yourTable 
LIMIT 0,10;
```

It may not be the most elegant solution, as you get this number repeated in all rows, but it solves your problem and should be pretty performant.

**Elegant option:**

use a stored procedure with an output parameter - the procedure would contain 2 queries but you would have one elegant call to a stored procedure.

Comment: Do you know how this can be implemented with JPA?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Sorry, I don't know Java at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total count (to calculate total pages) then you need two queries, there is no way around it in hibernate (I'm saying that because you could be able (not sure though) to build a nasty SQL query where you merge the count query with the select query, but it's really not worth it and I won't do it even for optimization).

see: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-pagination

that being said if you have the option then you can switch to not have a definitive number of pages (your UI can be virtual scrolling or just [Previous / Next] without ending.

Comment: Is there any solution with JPA?

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option in Hibernate to do this with a single query, but it is not part of JPA.

[ScrollableResults](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html) works against an open JDBC `ResultSet` behind the scenes, which you can then advance to the last row.

For example, starting from the JPA Query:

```
    ScrollableResults scrollableResults = jpaQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class).scroll();
    scrollableResults.scroll(offset);
    // Extract rows ...
    while (scrollableResults.next()) {
        PaymentTransactions paymentTransactions = (PaymentTransactions) scrollableResults.get(0);
        // ... process and check count
    }
    // Find the last row
    scrollableResults.last();
    int totalCount = scrollableResults.getRowNumber() + 1;
```

Note this will not necessarily be more efficient than the two query option though - especially for a large number of results.